# I can't see labels in GE of points exported from shp to kml in Qgis

Tags: qgis, labeling, point, kml, google-earth-pro

I have created a shp layer in Qgis (version 2.12.3-Lyon) with points. I want to see it in Google Earth, so I saved the shp as a kml. When I open it in GE Pro, I don't see the labels, only if I click on the icon, I see the field (label) attach to it.

I can change the name of each point in the left column of GE, and so the label appears, but I would like it to be automatically done.

Also, if I create a point directly in GE, I see the label right away, so... is there something I can do when exporting in Qgis from shp to kml?

The picture below shows four yellow points I exported from shp to kml, I manually changed the name of number 1 and 2, so the lable appears in the map. There is also one red point named Example which I created directly in Google Earth.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must properly specify Name and Description fields. See screenshot:

[image]

Also there are several options, that can be configured during exporting to KML (depends of selected driver):

1. http://gdal.org/drv_kml.html
2. http://gdal.org/drv_libkml.html