# How to ensure proper labeling from QGIS 2.18 to Google Maps layer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, google-maps, convert, qgis-2.18

I am having trouble with a misplaced label for my field in Google Maps after I imported the .kml file which was converted from a .shp file in QGIS 2.18.  The file contains the ward districts for my township and, as you see marked in the image below, the label for Ward 1 is duplicated (presumably due to its larger geographic area) and misplaced in the Ward 2 area.

Without using the Google Maps API or any programming, is it possible to correct this kind of mislabeling or do I have to accept the auto-labeling feature that comes with Google Maps as is?  Similar to a previous [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207303/i-cant-see-labels-in-ge-of-points-exported-from-shp-to-kml-in-qgis), I did save my vector layer properly in QGIS as described in the answer and then set my label option in Google Maps.  I just don't have any control over where my labels appear on the map.

[image: Ward Districts]

Comment: are you sure there is not a small ward 1 "island" down there?

Comment: Yes, I am certain there are no non-contiguous areas for Ward 1.  I don't think there is a solution to this problem without programming knowledge.